# execl function usage in C programming language

Tags: c, unix, posix

What is the usage of `execl` command?

```
excel("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmdstring, (char *)0);
_exit(127);
```

Can anyone explain each statement used in `execl` command?
And why only `_exit(127)` and not `exit(0)`.

What is `127` number indicating?

Comment: what language/OS/environment is the `excel` function embedded in? (The most important question). `_exit(127)` would be the standard *nix return code to indicate 'command not found'. Good luck.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "UNIX programming language."  Do you mean C?  (And are you possibly misreading `execl` or `execle`?)

Answer (score 3):

`execl` is one of the several functions (`exec*`) that let you replace the current code of your process with the one provided by the file (an executable one) specified as the first argument. The whole space of your process is replaced by a fresh one... Other arguments serve as arguments to the command. A process is a kind of system structure controlling execution of some code. `exec` lets you *mutate* that code.

In the case `exec` succeed then the old code is *forgotten*, you will never be able to get back into it. This is not a function call.

In the case `exec` fails then execution continues, and in your case a call to `_exit` is made. `_exit` is a system function designed to stop execution of the current process, leading to its death. `exit` is a C-function that does the same at C-level, roughly closing C-streams and calling `_exit`.

The value provided (`127`) is used to communicate some information about the termination of this process to the process that launched it (process are launched by the use of `fork`, a call that *clones* a process). The value can be any eight bit value, but 0 is used to denote a process that terminated correctly, and any other non 0 value to denote a process that terminated in some abnormal condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can type 
`man execl`
in the terminal for more information on the `execl` command.